Safari 17.5 can't scroll flexbox container
So, it seems like with the new update for mobile Safari (17.5) scrolling inside of flexbox containers has stopped working!!
Is this only happening to me? cause I expected the internet to be filled with complains and sites breaking left and right
Here is an example I have created: https://codepen.io/xjimdim/pen/KKLqwOr
        <body>
          <div class="supercontainer">
            <div class="container">
              <div class="child">
                <div class="grandchild">1</div>
                <div class="grandchild">2</div>
                <div class="grandchild">3</div>
                <div class="grandchild">4</div>
                <div class="grandchild">5</div>
                <div class="grandchild">6</div>
                <div class="grandchild">7</div>
                <div class="grandchild">8</div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

        </body>


        .container {
            padding: 10px;
            overflow-y: auto;
            min-height: 150px;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            justify-content: flex-end;
            min-height: 0;
        }

        .supercontainer {
            max-height: 70vh;
            background: red;
            display: flex;
        }

        .child {
            min-height: 0;
        }

        .grandchild {
            height: 100px;
            display: flex;
            background: orange;
            color: white;
            width: 300px;
            align-items:center;
            justify-content: center;
            margin-bottom: 1rem;
        }

In all other browsers the .container element has a scrollbar and you can scroll through its children but on Safari 17.5 it shows like container has overflow hidden! (all other versions of safari seem to work ok)
Any ideas on how to fix this? Or anyone else experiencing this crazy weird issue?

Also having issues with scrolling after latest safari update. Using a virtual scroll component. Still diagnosing but this update has been a nightmare :( Scroll bar no longer moves, either.
